# How to define custom filename placeholder in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

Currently I am defining `output.filename = 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].js'`

But `[hash]` and `[chunkhash]` is not checksum of the file itself, but checksum of whole bundle / whole chunk.

Actual md5 of file is means more for me for managing files on CDN. For example `[hash]`/`[chunkhash]` remain the same for minified and unminified builds and I can't rely on it to recognize changed files.

Nice to have `[filehash]` and `[size]` placeholders for `output.filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can use [this](https://github.com/erm0l0v/webpack-md5-hash) plugin.

> **webpack-md5-hash**
>
> Plugin to replace a standard webpack chunkhash with md5.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question of how one can add new placeholders…

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have no idea how to create new placeholders (searching for this myself) but I do know that in recent versions of webpack, you can use `[contenthash]` instead of `[hash]` or `[chunkhash]` to get a hash of the file itself.